# Can I resolve as singleton by default in Laravel?

Tags: singleton, laravel-8

I am using `Laravel 8`.

Laravel supports [Zero Configuration Resolution](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#zero-configuration-resolution), which means that any class with an empty constructor can be automatically injected without the need to specifically configure it.

However, each time I try to resolve such classes, a new object is being instatiated. If I want to create a `singleton` instead, I need to [specifically bind it](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#binding-a-singleton) in a service provider.

Is there a way to automatically define all classes resolved with `Zero Configuration Resolution` as `singletons` by default?